# Erro do comando INSERT no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-insert

Tenho uma aplicação web no visual studio onde estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem sempre que tento dar um comando insert

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Funcionario' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.'

Código do C#:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Funcionario ON " +
            "INSERT INTO Funcionario VALUES ('" + func.nome + "'," + func.salarioBase + "," + func.inss + "," + func.irrf + "," + func.hrsExtras + "," + func.dependentes + "," + func.salarioLiquido + ")" +
            "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Funcionaio OFF";
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

Estrutura da tabela :

```
create table Funcionario(cod_Func int identity (1,1),nome varchar (50),salarioBase decimal,inss decimal,irrf decimal,qtdHoraExtra int,dependente int,salarioLiquido decimal);
```

Se eu tento inserir especificando os campos da tabela, o erro passa a ser outro

Insert :

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Funcionario ON " +
            "INSERT INTO Funcionario (nome,salarioBase,inss,irrf,qtdHoraExtra,dependente,salarioLiquido) VALUES ('" + func.nome + "'," + func.salarioBase + "," + func.inss + "," + func.irrf + "," + func.hrsExtras + "," + func.dependentes + "," + func.salarioLiquido + ")";
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

Erro:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.'

Não entendo por que do erro, visto que `cod_Func` é **identity**, ou seja, não podemos setar seu valor.

Comment: o seu comando não teria que ser `INSERT INTO Funcionarios (COLUNAS) values (VALORES_A_SEREM_INSERIDOS)`?

Comment: O erro é auto-explicativo: Um valor explícito para a coluna de identidade na tabela' Funcionario 'só pode ser especificado quando uma lista de colunas é usada e IDENTITY_INSERT está LIGADO

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Ai é que está, mesmo eu deixando IDENTITY_INSERT como ON, ele continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: @R.Santos Eu tentei desse jeito que você me disse, só que ele exibe a seguinte mensagem : "There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

Comment: O numero de colunas e de valores que você esta passando no comando de Insert são diferentes esse é o erro agora, mostar como ficou teu INSERT agora com as colunas

Comment: @R.Santos Inseri mais algumas informações na pergunta, mas ainda assim continua dando o mesmo erro ...

Comment: Faça um teste tente alterar a estrutura de sua tabela alterando o `cod_Func` para integer e depois tente inserir um registro com um codigo de funcionário junto, para ver se ocorre algum erro

Comment: Eu já fiz isso, ele conseguiu inserir normalmente os dados, ele só dá erro quando altero o cod_Func para Identity

Comment: A sua ideia é que o cod_func seja algo unico e auto_incremet isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você define `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` como `ON` mas não passa o `cod_Func` no comando `Insert`.

Segundo a documentação: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188059%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Se você habilitou a opção para inserir a coluna Identity, deve passar ela no comando.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você deve declarar as colunas que serão inseridas na sua instrução de `insert`. Outra coisa muito importante, nunca concatene instruções SQL como você está fazendo, se você concatenar suas instruções SQL, seu sistema estará vulnerável a [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)

Com o `SqlDataSource` não sei como fica, mas estou colocando na minha resposta um exemplo usando o `SqlCommand`.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=StackOverflow;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    conn.Open();
    string insert = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Funcionario]
                            ([nome]
                            ,[salarioBase]
                            ,[inss]
                            ,[irrf]
                            ,[qtdHoraExtra]
                            ,[dependente]
                            ,[salarioLiquido])
                        VALUES
                            (@nome
                            , @salarioBase
                            , @inss
                            , @irrf
                            , @qtdHoraExtra
                            , @dependente
                            , @salarioLiquido)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insert, conn);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("nome", func.nome));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("salarioBase", func.salarioBase));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("inss", func.inss));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("irrf", func.irrf));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("qtdHoraExtra", func.qtdHoraExtra));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("salarioLiquido", func.dependente));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("dependente", func.dependente));

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No meu código haviam dois erros:

**1-** Eu estava usando a variação mais simples do comando INSERT, onde precisaria apenas especificar a tabela e os valores (`INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (X)`), e isso foi um erro, pois acredito eu, essa variação mais simples não leva em conta campos **Identity**, incluindo eles nas colunas à serem preenchidas;

**2-** O comando `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Tabela ON/OFF` diz ao programa se campos **Identity** devem ser levados em consideração ou não. Consideremos a seguinte instrução :

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Funcionario ON " +
        "INSERT INTO Funcionario (nome,salarioBase,inss,irrf,qtdHoraExtra,dependente,salarioLiquido) VALUES ('" + func.nome + "'," + func.salarioBase + "," + func.inss + "," + func.irrf + "," + func.hrsExtras + "," + func.dependentes + "," + func.salarioLiquido + ")";
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

Logo, se vê que estou dizendo que campos **Identity** DEVEM ser levados em consideração, porém, não atribuo nenhum valor a ele na coluna `VALUES`, por isso do erro de ter menos campos do que o especificado.

Por fim, é necessário alterar apenas o `ON` pelo `OFF` que funcionará normalmente